# Tkinter MessageBox Align

Tags: tkinter

[image: Look at the img.]

Can some one help me with aligning the text in the message box to the center. Thanks

---

**EDIT:** Expected result:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "center" ? center one line to another, center text in window rectangle ? you can always create own window (using `tk.Toplevel` with `Label` and align text: [example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/align-grid-pack). BTW: it looks like you have spaces after `\n`.

Comment: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC86459.jpeg look at the picture... I want the text is on the center. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Toplevel()` to create own message window and then you can do what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def about():
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.title("ABOUT")
    
    l = tk.Label(win, text="One\ntwo two\nThree Three Three", bg='white')
    l.pack(ipadx=50, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)
    
    b = tk.Button(win, text="OK", command=win.destroy)
    b.pack(pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=20, side='right')
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="About", command=about)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Linux:

[image]

---

**BTW:** you can find file with messagebox code

```
import tkinter.messagebox

print(tkinter.messagebox.__file__)
```

and then open in editor to see how it was made.

---

**EDIT:** you can also create class `MsgBox` and use it many times.

Example shows how to change some elements in class: label font, button text and position

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---
# you can put this in separated file (it will need `import tkinter`)

import tkinter 

class MsgBox(tkinter.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, title="MsgBox", message="Hello World"):
        tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.title(title)
        
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text=message)
        self.label['bg'] = 'white'
        self.label.pack(ipadx=50, ipady=10, fill='both', expand=True)

        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text="OK")
        self.button['command'] = self.destroy
        self.button.pack(pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=20, side='right')
        
# --- functions ---

def about():

    msg = MsgBox("ABOUT", "One\nTwo Two\nThree Three Three")
    msg.label['font'] = 'Verdana 20 bold'
    msg.button['text'] = 'Close'
    msg.button.pack(side='left')
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="About", command=about)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
b.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

code on GitHub: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/messagebox/own-messagebox](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/messagebox/own-messagebox)