# Tkinter pop-up window with check button, not able to get check button states

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a pop up window ,on press of a button on main window. The pop up window have many check buttons, I need to get the state of the check buttons back to main window and also to make use of a select all and deselect all button. But I am getting error using the variables, and not able to pass the states back to main window.

Here is the program I wrote:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()
state=[[]]

def popup(x):

    def select_clear_states():
        global Vars, all_states
        states = all_states.get()

        if states == 0:
            for I in range(len(Vars)):
                Vars[I].set(0)
        if states == 1:
            for I in range(len(Vars)):
                Vars[I].set(1)

    Vars = []

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    all_states = Tkinter.IntVar()
    select_all = Tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text = "select/deselect all",variable = all_states, command = select_clear_states)
    select_all.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1)

    for n in range(10):

        var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        Vars.append(var)
        checkbox = Tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text = n+1, variable= Vars[n])
        checkbox.grid(row = n+1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1)

    root.mainloop()


A = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello1",command=lambda: popup(1))
A.pack()

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello2",command=lambda: popup(2))
B.pack()

C = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello3",command=lambda: popup(3))
C.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

am not able to make use of the variables Vars all_state and state[[]], to get he state of the check button.am getting this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Synapse\Documents\Neo\Tutorial\python_tutorial\button.py", line 11, in select_clear_states
      states = all_states.get()
  NameError: global name 'all_states' is not defined
```

I should be able to use select/deselectall button and also able to get back all states of each check button to main window.

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback).

Comment: you create `all_states` inside `popup()` so it is not global variable. Create outside all function `all_states = None` and this will be global variable. And then use `global all_states` in both functions to inform functions that they have to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

Comment: BTW: you will have the same problem with `Vars`

Comment: BTW: `Tkinter` should have only one `Tk()` window. To create second/third window use `Toplevel()`. And `Tkinter` should have only one `mainloop()`. Two loops make problem with values in variables.

Comment: BTW: today question: [how to create About Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325665/tkinter-messagebox-align/41336253#41336253)

Comment: ya it works, that was good information

Answer (score 2):

Example code using class.

It use `Toplevel()` to create PopUp because `Tkinter` should have only one `Tk()` window.

And it use only one `mainloop()` because more loops make problem with values in variables.

It can created different number of checkboxes.

It needs more work - ie. to return values - but now you can use `win.states` to get states of all checkboxes (or to set them).

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class PopUp(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, number=10):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        # - global checkbox to set all "small" checkboxes -

        self.global_state = tk.BooleanVar()

        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="select/deselect all",
                            variable=self.global_state,
                            command=self.select_clear_states)
        cb.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=1)

        # - "small" checkboxes -

        self.states = []

        for n in range(1, number+1):
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=str(n), variable=var)
            cb.grid(row=n, column=0, padx=5, pady=1)
            self.states.append(var)


    def select_clear_states(self):
        # get global checkbox
        state = self.global_state.get()

        # set all "small" checkboxes
        for x in self.states:
            x.set(state)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def popup(num):

    win = PopUp(num)
    #win.states[1].set(True)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="5 checkboxes", command=lambda:popup(5))
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="10 checkboxes", command=lambda:popup(10))
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="3 checkboxes", command=lambda:popup(3))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bro, Do you know how to add a scroll bar to this popup window? When passing a large number to the popup function (example: popup(100)) a part of the popup window is in outer of the screen area.

Comment: @ChamodDissanayake scrollbar works only with widget `Text`, `Listbox` or `Canvas`. The only method is to use `Canvas` with `Frame` and `Scrollbar` to create [ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas) - and then you can put other elements inside `ScrolledFrame` to scroll me.